# Download file using .net web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, filestream

I'm trying to download PDF file to my local storage downloads folder from a specific folder location using .net web API.
Currently I'm getting the correct file from swagger, but it will only download when I click the download option in swagger UI API call.

Here's the code for that:

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetGeneratedEReceipt(string fileName) 
{  
    FileStreamResult? fileOutput = null;
    try
    {
      string assetPath = _appSettings.EReceiptBasePath;
      assetPath = "Pictures";

      string genaratedfilename = string.Concat(fileName, ".pdf");

      string path = Path.Combine(assetPath, genaratedfilename);

         if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
         {
           fileOutput = new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = fileName };
         } 
     }
     catch (System.Exception)
     {
         throw;
     }

     return fileOutput;
 }
```

and here's the swagger UI.

[image: swagger ui]

When I click the download button, it will download the file to folder.
Currently I'm using .net 6 version,
but I want automatically download the file when a API call occurs. How can I do that?

I need to automated the download part.

Comment: Then create a PowerShell script or console application that issues the API call and downloads the file?

Comment: The question is unclear (and the code too long, it can be replaced with `return File(path);`). What do you mean `automatically download the file when api call occur`? Whatever is making the call saves the file. If the code is made by a browser, the browser saves the file. If it's made by a program, the program should save the file

Comment: It could be something as simple as `curl https://your-domain/GetGeneratedEReceipt?fileName=file`. cURL will save the retrieved file to disk using its name. So would all download managers and utilities